# I'm having problems making an app that finds user lat/lng and device IMEI

Tags: java, android, location

i want to make a simple android app that shows me the user location and in a toast the device IMEI. i can't figure out what's the problem because i'm new to android-studio and build output doesn't show me the error line.

```
package com.example.mainactivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FusedLocationProviderClient client;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestPermission();

    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.Locatie);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }

  client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new 
 OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                    if(location!= null) {

                    }


                }
            })
        }
    });

}
private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
}

public String getDeviceIMEI() {
    String deviceUniqueIdentifier = null;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(null != tm) {
        deviceUniqueIdentifier = tm.getDeviceId();

    }
    if(null == deviceUniqueIdentifier || 0 == 
deviceUniqueIdentifier.length()) {
        deviceUniqueIdentifier = 
Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), 
Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, deviceUniqueIdentifier, 300);
    toast.show();
    return deviceUniqueIdentifier;

}

}
```

i expect to see the lat and the lnf of the device and the imei on toast windows. i don t think is very usefull but i'm new to android.

Comment: Did you add the permissions in the manifest?

Comment: yes, the premission is in manifest file

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: Did you grant location permission? You call return; when permission is not granted. Where do you call getDeviceIMEI(), which actually show the Toast? @TudorStanciulescu

Comment: no, the app doesn't work, it shows me errors

Comment: `errors` which errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this 3 `permission` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Change the details according to your Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.Chk);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location!=null){
                            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

                            Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            Double latitude = location.getLatitude();

                            textView.setText(String.valueOf(longitude+ "  "+latitude));

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Chk"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:text="Check Location"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In build.gradle(Application) add this :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
}
```

And Add this dependency in build.gradle(Module: app):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
```

Here is my Screenshot: 
[image: Check]

Comment: you mean to delete all my location code and replace with this?

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu This one is another way to fetch location. You can use FusedLocationProvider like the one you used in your code. Try to put log and check the callback are getting executed or not.

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu You can use this method to fetch your Location and imei .

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu Check this now

Comment: @TudorStanciulescu Check now

Answer (score 0):

```
i used locationManager but in the textView i set to show me the lat and long, it doesn't show me anything
package com.example.locatieimei;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

private TextView textView;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_textview);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
 ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) 
 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
 permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the 
 documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = 
 locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    onLocationChanged(location);




}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitute  = location.getLatitude();
    textView.setText("Longitudine"+longitude+ "\n"+"Latitudine"+latitute);

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

 }
}
i use the locationManager but on the textView i set to show me the lat and long, 
 still show me the Hello World. 
this is the xml
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/id_textview"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and yes, i used the permission in manifest

Comment: give me some time i am checking it .

Comment: no problem @Muntasir Aonik  i still can't figure out why it doesn't work to show me the location on the textView

Comment: Check my latest answer .

Comment: when i press the check location button on app it doesn't work. it doesn't happen anything

Comment: Did you allow the permission's for the app? and turn on your location?

Comment: Go to app info and allow location permission for app. You have to allow it manually because i didn't implement the automatic system . And your mobile location service must be on.

Comment: yes. that was the problem, thank you @muntasir aonik

Comment: One more thing if you need to submit your demo code don't answer the question . You can edit your question and add the demo code .